# SLider on hover text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a newbie in js and jquery. How can I make this thing? I have four texts, when I hover on each of them I need to see slider of 2 two images which belongs to certain text. Help me if you can. I have just this code:

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/1.png);
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/8.png);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/9.png);
}

p3:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/11.png);
}

p4:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/5.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p1>
  <p>text1</p>
</p1>
<p2>
  <p>text2</p>
</p2>
<p3>
  <p>text3</p>
</p3>
<p4>
  <p>text4</p>
</p4>
<div class="pic"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<p1>
    <p>text1</p>
</p1>
<div class="pic"></div>
<p2>
    <p>text2</p>
</p2>
<div class="pic"></div>
<p3>
    <p>text3</p>
</p3>
<div class="pic"></div>
<p4>
    <p>text4</p>
</p4>
<div class="pic"></div>

// css 

.pic {
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover+.pic {
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/8.png);
}

p2:hover+.pic {
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/9.png);
} 

p3:hover+.pic {
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
   background-image: url(img/scr-img/11.png);
}    

p4:hover+.pic {
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/5.png);
}
```

Just make sure image url is good

Comment: It should work for all texts let me share you a link with codepen.

Comment: Gajic, I just changed + to ~

Comment: Gajic, but it is still not a slider. How can I make it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KroLQd Ok here you can check that it changes. But slider you can't make with just css. I thought you want only to change image on hover . If you want slider you can check here https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Comment: Gajic, I still have no idea how can I do that(

Comment: You can check here for simple slideshow https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zKbYzP